# How can I tweak my procedure to bypass exact fetch returns more than one requested number

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_PROC (
       V_P      IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL)
    AS   
       V_DATE TIMESTAMP:=SYSDATE;
       V_TAB       VARCHAR2(10);
    BEGIN
       IF V_P = 'P' THEN

            SELECT CUR_DATE, TGT_TAB
                   INTO V_DATE, V_TAB
            FROM TEMP_L
                WHERE P='P'
                AND END_TIME IS NULL 
                AND COMPLETE_IND IS NULL;

            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE '||V_TAB;

                IF V_TAB = 'TEMP_V' THEN
                    INSERT INTO TEMP_V
                    SELECT V FROM REP_TAB
                ELSE
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP_V';
                    INSERT INTO TEMP_V
                    SELECT V FROM REP_TAB
                END IF;

                 IF V_TAB = 'TEMP_T' THEN
                    INSERT INTO TEMP_V
                    SELECT V FROM REP_TAB
                 ELSE
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP_T';
                    INSERT INTO TEMP_V
                    SELECT V FROM REP_TAB
                 END IF;
    END;
```

My above procedure has an IN parameter that takes values such as 'P'. If INput value is 'P'
then SELECT CUR_DATE and TGT_TAB into two separate variables V_DATE and V_TAB from table TEMP_L where two of the columns return null values. For the records that returns true then apply this logic, If variable V_TAB which fetches records from TGT_TAB, = 'TEMP_V'(I realized it might return more than 1 record and different one and this is why I am asking for help) then insert into.. else insert into..

Now here is the problem, my SELECT INTO variables can only hold 1 value and sometimes there might be more than one record that returns null and with different values in TGT_TAB. Sometimes it will be TEMP_V, sometimes it will be TEMP_T etc.

How do I change my script in order to run the bottom part of the script successfully?
Since more than one records will be returned, my variable will return error:exact fetch returns more than one requested number. I tried using bulk collect, but the collections only work in loops and I am not sure how to apply it to my below requirement. I need to insert them base on the return values,'TEMP_V', 'TEMP_T', and so on basically.

```
                   IF V_TAB = 'TEMP_V' THEN
                        INSERT INTO TEMP_V
                        SELECT V FROM REP_TAB
                    ELSE
                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP_V';
                        INSERT INTO TEMP_V
                        SELECT V FROM REP_TAB
                    END IF;

                    IF V_TAB = 'TEMP_T' THEN
                        INSERT INTO TEMP_V
                        SELECT V FROM REP_TAB
                    ELSE
                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP_T';
                        INSERT INTO TEMP_V
                        SELECT V FROM REP_TAB
                    END IF;
```

Any help will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_PROC (
  V_P      IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL)
AS   
BEGIN
  IF V_P = 'P' THEN
    FOR aRow IN (SELECT CUR_DATE, TGT_TAB
                   FROM TEMP_L
                   WHERE P='P'
                     AND END_TIME IS NULL 
                     AND COMPLETE_IND IS NULL)
    LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE '|| aRow.TGT_TAB;

      IF aRow.TGT_TAB = 'TEMP_V' THEN
        INSERT INTO TEMP_V
          SELECT V FROM REP_TAB;
      ELSE
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP_V';

        INSERT INTO TEMP_V
          SELECT V FROM REP_TAB;
      END IF;

      IF aRow.TGT_TAB = 'TEMP_T' THEN
        INSERT INTO TEMP_V
          SELECT V FROM REP_TAB;
      ELSE
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP_T';

        INSERT INTO TEMP_V
          SELECT V FROM REP_TAB;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
END SP_PROC;
```

This replaces the singleton SELECT in the original code with a cursor loop that allows all rows matching the SELECT criteria to be processed.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide how you want to process the case where you return multiple rows in your select.  Do you want to process all of the rows?  The last row? The first row?  Once that decision is made, you can use a FOR loop (or an OPEN...FETCH...CLOSE loop) to process the appropriate row(s) in TEMP_L.

Comment: I will use the earliest CUR_DATE. It will be something like below.
            SELECT CUR_DATE, TGT_TAB
                   INTO V_DATE, V_TAB
            FROM TEMP_L
                WHERE P='P'
                AND END_TIME IS NULL 
                AND COMPLETE_IND IS NULL
                AND START_TIME =(SELECT MIN(CUR_DATE) 
                               FROM TEMP_L 
                                WHERE END_TIME IS NULL 
                                AND COMPLETE_IND IS NULL
                                AND PARA='P');

Can you give me an example how it can be done?